# How to Filter a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, csv

I am working with CSV and Java. I know how to read the file and print the values from the file, but do not know how to find specific values. I have tried to get the values into an arraylist then use the method indexof() but that hasn't worked.  Is there a way to pull the value out and print it?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Have you tried anything?

Comment: No I have not, I was thinking of using an arraylist then adding and removing from there. @tnw

Comment: Assume that there *is* a way to do that, try something, and if you get stuck ask about what you tried. Please see [Why is "is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `country.csv` with content:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"
```

One of the way to read this file and concurrently filter needed fields. For example, it shown how we can filter different countries by country code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CSVReader {

    static Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String csvFile = "/home/../country.csv";
        String line = "";
        String cvsSplitBy = ",";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                // use comma as separator
                String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
                for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
                    map.put(country[4], country[5]);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String code = entry.getKey();
            String name = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Country [code= " + code + " , name=" + name + "]");
        }
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Country [code= "CN" , name="China"]
Country [code= "JP" , name="Japan"]
Country [code= "AU" , name="Australia"]
Country [code= "TH" , name="Thailand"]
```

Comment: How can we filter the file when it isn't read? We have to read it and later filter the content or do it concurrently

Comment: Yes that is true, but I know how to read the file, but not how to filter it. @VasylLyashkevych

Comment: Thanks mate, you're a homie :). @VasylLyashkevych